# Cannot login in web app via C#

Tags: c#, django

I'm trying to log in at http://carkit.kg (django app) via C# with following code

```
HttpWebRequest tokenRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://carkit.kg");
tokenRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
string token = "";
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)tokenRequest.GetResponse()) {
    token = response.Cookies["csrftoken"].ToString().Split('=')[1];
}

HttpWebRequest loginRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://carkit.kg");

var cache = new CredentialCache();
cache.Add(new Uri("http://carkit.kg"), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(username, password));
loginRequest.Credentials = cache;
loginRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;

loginRequest.Method = "POST";
loginRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
loginRequest.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("csrftoken", token) {Domain="carkit.kg"});
Debug.Log(token);

byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&csrfmiddlewaretoken=" + token);


loginRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
loginRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
loginRequest.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
loginRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
//loginRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
loginRequest.Headers.Add("Origin", "http://carkit.kg");
loginRequest.Referer = "http://carkit.kg/";
loginRequest.Headers.Add("UpgradeInsecureRequests", "1");
loginRequest.Headers.Add("XCompress", "null");
loginRequest.Headers.Add("ContentType", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
loginRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36";
loginRequest.Headers.Add("X-CSRFToken",token);
loginRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
loginRequest.Timeout = 3000;
loginRequest.GetRequestStream().Write(data, 0, data.Length);
loginRequest.Headers.Add("X-CSRFToken", token);
HttpWebResponse authResponse = (HttpWebResponse)loginRequest.GetResponse();
Debug.Log(authResponse.ResponseUri);
```

Both requests running well, but last line returns incorrect uri (if login is correct it should redirect me to /game and stay at / in other case) - anyway it returns /. Redirect is enabled and you see which headers I've included into request. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just used django-rest-framework as authentication service and LogIn method got this representation:

```
public void LogIn(string username, string password)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://carkit.kg/api/v1/auth/login/");

    var postData = "username=" + username;
        postData += "&password=" + password;
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
    try {
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
            // Successful login
        } 
        else {
            serverMessenger.SendErrorMessage(0);
            Debug.LogError("Cannot Find User. TryToLogin finished");
        }
    } catch (WebException e) {
        serverMessenger.SendErrorMessage(0);
        Debug.LogError("Cannot Find User. TryToLogin finished");
    }
}
```